# Application crash when close mail composer view in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, email

One of application i am using mail composer for sending mail but unfortunately when i click on send,save or cancel mail then application crash.
Even application only support portrait mode and didn't implemented any code for change orientation.
**Code for Mail Composer method** :-

```
  MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:MAIL_EMAIL]];
[mailViewController setSubject:MAIL_SUBJECT];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:MAIL_MESSAGE isHTML:NO];
[self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

**Mail Composer Delegate Method** :-

```
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];

```
**Error** :-

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0306d1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02dec8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0306cfbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x01bdb3ec -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 580
    4   UIKit                               0x01e793d5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2330
    5   UIKit                               0x01bd8bda -[UIViewController _dismissViewControllerWithTransition:from:completion:] + 1647
    6   UIKit                               0x01bd852e -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 1281
    7   UIKit                               0x01bd852e -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 1281
    8   UIKit                               0x01bd9729 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 57
    9   TestApp                            0x0004c794 -[HelpViewController mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:] + 340
    10  MessageUI                           0x019ba012 -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController _notifyCompositionDidFinish] + 535
    11  MessageUI                           0x019b9d98 -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController compositionFinishedWithResult:error:] + 210
    12  MessageUI                           0x019bbc5d -[MFMailComposeRemoteViewController serviceCompositionFinishedWithResult:error:] + 84
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0306191d __invoking___ + 29
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0306182a -[NSInvocation invoke] + 362
    15  UIKit                               0x020d5f0f __63-[_UIViewServiceInterface connection:handleInvocation:isReply:]_block_invoke + 36
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0336c7b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x033814d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0336f726 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x030d243e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x030135cb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x030129d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x030127eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x040055ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0400542b GSEventRun + 104
    25  UIKit                               0x01aacf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    26  TestApp                            0x0001e30d main + 141
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x035b670d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your UIViewController subclass (the one you're using to present the mail composer)

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What's written in your info.plist under "supportedInterfaceOrientations"?

Comment: Portrait (bottom home button)

Comment: And you've added the above code to HelpViewController?